# How many slaves in a solr master-slave model?

Tags: solr, master-slave

I'm using Solr4. In my one solr solrconfig.xml, I can find the config:

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler">
<lst name="master">
<str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>
<str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
<str name="confFiles">schema.xml,stopwords.txt,elevate.xml</str>
<str name="commitReserveDuration">00:00:10</str>
<str name="maxNumberOfBackups">1</str>
</requestHandler>
```

I another solr solrconfig.xml, I can find the config:

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler">
<lst name="slave">
<str name="masterUrl">http://xxxxx:8389/solr/collection/replication</str>
<str name="pollInterval">00:00:20</str>
<str name="compression">internal</str>
<str name="httpConnTimeout">5000</str>
<str name="httpReadTimeout">10000</str>
<str name="httpBasicAuthUser">username</str>
<str name="httpBasicAuthPassword">password</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I can only find one slave in my production, but someone said that we have more than one slave,but how can i find them?
HOPE FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which container you're using for Solr4, you can look at the access log for the container and see the IPs of all hosts that are calling your  `/replication` end point:

This is from an Solr4 installation running under tomcat (in the `localhost_access_log.<date>` files:

```
192.168.x.x - - [18/Nov/2016:04:15:30 +0100] "GET /solr/corename/replication?command=indexversion&wt=javabin&qt=%2Freplication&version=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 80
```

Comment: yes, that is the answer. I'm using jetty9. I will find the log file and all the slaves.